# Extension theorem of twice continuously differentiable functions?

Tags: functions

Is there a theorem which guarantees me that any function $f$ with bounded first and second order derivatives defined over a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be extended to a twice continuously differentiable function $F$ on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition is not enough. Since initially you only require the function have bounded second derivative on a compact subset, since differentiable doesn't imply continuous differentiable, it may not be continuous differentiable on the compact set, so it can't be extended to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

An example is 
$$f(x) = x^{4} \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$f(0) = 0$$

The $2$nd derivative of $f(x)$ exists for each value of $x$, bounded at the neighborhood of $0$ but not continuous at  $x = 0$.

Comment: Good point! Thank you.  If you add continously differentiable, does there then exist such a theorem?
(I dont know if this is somehow important, but in my particular case I have a symmetric function f(x,y))